# load scripts and css with ajax loaded contents

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a page that contains a menu sidebar with links and a div the load ajax content from other pages in it, the content load successfully but the scripts and css not work, also i already use html 5 history load load content from other pages.

```
$(function () {

    $('.menuAnchor').click(function (e) {
        href = $(this).attr("href");
        loadContent(href);
        // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
        history.pushState('', 'New URL: ' + href, href);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        console.log("pathname: " + location.pathname);
        loadContent(location.pathname);
    };
});

function loadContent(url) {
    // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
    $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
        $(".contn_btm_mid_bg").html($(data).find('.contn_btm_mid_bg').html());
        //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(".contn_btm_mid_bg");
    });

    // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
    $('li').removeClass('current');
    $('a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('current');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok do one thing load your css and js externally using code

```
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "/styles/yourcss.css"
}).appendTo("head");
```

same for js

Comment: i put this for css but for scripts , Can i use the same logic as $("<scripts/>",{ .... and how can i put many js in this

Comment: look at here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});